# How to pass values from child component to parent in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I have these functional components:

`CHILD:`

```
import React from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const ProductsQtde = props => {

    let [productQtde, setProductQtde] = React.useState(1)

    const changeQtde = arg => {
        if (arg === "increase") {
            setProductQtde(productQtde + 1)
        } else if (arg === 'decrease') {
            productQtde > 1 ? setProductQtde(productQtde - 1) : setProductQtde(1)
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="product-qtde d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center border">
            <p style={{margin: '0'}}>{productQtde}</p>
            <div className="product-qtde-arrows d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
                <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => changeQtde('increase')} icon="chevron-up" size="xs"/>
                <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => changeQtde('decrease')} icon="chevron-down" size="xs"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductsQtde
```

`PARENT:`

```
import React from 'react'

import ProductQtde from '../../Shared/UI/ProductsQtde/ProductsQtde'


    const Cart = props => {
    
        return (
            <div>
                <ProductQtde />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Cart
```

This is the result:

[image]

As can be seen it is kind of an input number, so, its function is to increase and to decrease the quantitity of whatever it's needed.

However, since it is a shared component and I'd like to make it functional and not just an UI component, I am setting its values in the component itself with the state `productQtde`, so that I don't need to create the function `changeQtde` in every parent component I am using `ProductsQtde`.

The point is, I want to keep changing this value in the child component, receive it in the parent and use it there. I know I could set a function and a state in the parent component and send it to the child as props, but as I said, I'd like to keep the functionality inside the child component.

Is it possible to do that?

I found out some posts and tutorials answering similar questions but none of them gave me the specific answer I need.

Comment: No matters what you want, if you want your value outside of your child component (so in the parent).... you need to create a relation between you child and the parent. A simple prop can do that.

Comment: This is anti pattern. Can you please elaborate? How do you want to access this value from the parent component? Do not break one directional flow (top down)

Comment: @Quentin Grisel There is a relationship, I understand that. But how would I pass a props from child to parent?

Comment: @Dupocas I understand that. `How do you want to access this value from the parent component?`, that is exactly what I'm asking, a way to do that.

Comment: `I know I could set a function and a state in the parent component and send it to the child as props` You litterally said you know how to do that dude. You prop is just the setter of a `useState`.

Comment: This is extremely unsual, if the logic is already encapsulated, why do you need to acess the value? What are you're planning to do in the parent with this value?

Comment: @Quentin Grisel Yes, but the question is how to do the opposite, send data from child to parent. What I said is that I know the other way around.

Comment: @Dupocas I know this is unusual. That's why I am asking. I explained why I am trying to do that in the question, so I could save a lot of lines, since I am using this child in several components.

Comment: @Berg_Durden I don't think it is even possible to do that, and if it is, well you should not. As Dupocas said it is anti pattern. Now, you could still use a context to do that. It is not exactly what you want, but maybe another way to organize you code to prevent these weird ideas to come out of you head haha

Comment: This is not what I've asked. You want to reuse the interals of the component to save a lot of lines. But what I'm asking is a description of the usecase. Something like: "I want to acess the value from the parent to dispatch an action, or log it on console"

Comment: @Quentin Grisel I see. I already have another way to do that, but doing it that way would make my life much easier. I'll keep looking and if don't find a way I'll put aside this 'weird idea' hehe

Comment: again, as Dupocas said, if you give us your usecase, maybe we can advice you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept digging, then with some help of this article I could reach my goal: https://dev.to/pnkfluffy/passing-data-from-child-to-parent-with-react-hooks-1ji3

The solution is quite simple and lies on a callback function.

What I am doing is passing a function to the child component as a props, this one in turn is calling this function and sending the updated value to the parent as an argument. `Cart` component receives the value as a parameter and use it to update its own state.

`CHILD:`

```
import React from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

const ProductsQtde = props => {

    let [productQtde, setProductQtde] = React.useState(1)

    const changeQtde = arg => {
        if (arg === "increase") {
            setProductQtde(productQtde + 1)
            props.changeQtdeCallBack(productQtde + 1) // => Callback function
        } else if (arg === 'decrease') {
            productQtde > 1 ? setProductQtde(productQtde - 1) : setProductQtde(1)
            props.changeQtdeCallBack(productQtde - 1) // => Callback function
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className="product-qtde d-flex justify-content-around align-items-center border">
            <p style={{margin: '0'}}>{productQtde}</p>
            <div className="product-qtde-arrows d-flex flex-column justify-content-between" >
                <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => changeQtde('increase')} icon="chevron-up" size="xs"/>
                <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => changeQtde('decrease')} icon="chevron-down" size="xs"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductsQtde
```

`PARENT:`

```
    import React from 'react'
    
    import ProductQtde from '../../Shared/UI/ProductsQtde/ProductsQtde'
    
    
    const Cart = props => {
    
        const [qtde, setQtde] = React.useState(1)
        
        
        return (
            <div>
                <ProductQtde 
                   {/* // => function being sent as props */}
                   changeQtdeCallBack={qtde => setQtde(qtde)} 
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Cart
```